# grpc один netty на несколько микросервисов

Tags: java, grpc

У себя в коде я создаю netty на определенный  порт и регистрирую сервис:

```
        Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8081)
            .addService(new HelloServiceImpl()).build();
```

Мне нужно создать другой микросервис, неужели нужно будет так же создавать server и вешать его на другой порт или есть возможность присоединиться к уже созданному и зарегистрировать там новый сервис ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете много раз вызывать addService():

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8081)
            .addService(new HelloServiceImpl())
            .addService(new HelloServiceImpl2())
            .build();
```